# Lucene index a large many-to-many relationship

Tags: lucene

I have a database with two primary tables:

1. The components table (50M rows),
2. The assemblies table (100K rows),

..and a many-to-many relationship between them (about 100K components per assembly), thus in total 10G relationships.

What's the best way to index the components such that I could query the index *for a given assembly*? Given the amount of relationships, I don't want to import them into the Lucene index, but am looking instead for a way to "join" with my external table on-the-fly.

Comment: how often you will need to update those many-to-many values? Should a change in the DB reflect in Lucene Index almost immediately? Or is it a one-time indexing which doesn't care about updations in the DB

Comment: and... the solution depends on your requirements.

Comment: My data is mostly static. I can even live with a read-only index. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solr supports multi-valued fields.  Not positive if Lucene supports them natively or not.  It's been a while for me.  If only one of the entities is searchable, which you mentioned is components, I would index all components with a field called "assemblies" or "assemblyIds" or something similar and include whatever metadata you need to identify the assemblies.

Then you can search components with

```
assemblyIds:(1, 2, 3)
```

To find components in assembly 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Yes, that would be the "brute force" implementation in which the relationships are simply imported into the Lucene index. But given the size of the relationship index (100GB), I don't really want to do it, I'm looking instead into a way to "join" the Lucene search with my external data source on the fly.

Comment: I believe Lucense and/or Solr have ways to search across multiple indexes and simulate a "join".  But I would resort to that as a last resort.  Part of what makes Lucene so fast to search through is its denormalization.  By organizing data into multiple indexes and joining, you are going against the grain.

Answer (score 0):

To be brief, you've got to process the data and Index it before you can search. Therefore, there exists no way to just "plug-in" Lucene to some data or database, instead you've to plug-in (process, parse, analyze, index, and query) the data it self to the Lucene.

---

rustyx: "My data is mostly static. I can even live with a read-only index."

In that case, you might use Lucene it self. You can iterate the datasource to add all the many-to-many relations to the Lucene index. How did you come up with that "100GB" size? People index millions and millions of documents using Lucene, I don't think it'd be a problem for you to index.

You can add multiple field instances to the index with different values ("components") in a document having an "assembly" field as well.

---

rustyx: "I'm looking instead into a way to "join" the Lucene search with my external data source on the fly"

If you need something seamless, you might try out the following framework which acts like a bridge between relational database and Lucene Index.

[Hibernate Search](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/) : In that tutorial, you might search for "@ManyToMany" keyword to find the exact section in the tutorial to get some idea.